# Adding an introductory paragraph to just one blog category - is this possible?

Tags: php, wordpress

I set up a website for my local astronomy group. It is a Wordpress site with what looks like two blogs:

http://bathastronomers.co.uk/

Obviously it is just one blog but I have set the menu to show two distinct categories on two different pages. There is the [regular blog](http://bathastronomers.co.uk/category/bath-astronomers/) for all posts in the "Bath Astronomers" category and the "[Dick Phillips' Archive](http://bathastronomers.co.uk/category/dick-phillips-archive/)" for all the posts in that category. It seemed like the best way to do it.

The problem is that now I want a simple introductory paragraph at the top of the Dick Phillips' Archive explaining who the man was and why the archive exists. I think I can hack this into the php somewhere (loop.php) but then I think it will appear at the top of both "blogs".

Is there some kind of conditional statement that will make it only appear on the archive page and not the regular blog?

Comment: This could be of some help http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: Thanks Graham. That sort of works - I can get the text to show up on the correct page only. Problem is that it is outside of the actual blog part of the theme. Weird. I will keep working on it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's sorted! I put the code in loop.php instead of categories.php. Thanks Graham - you really helped me to help myself!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a category template which will allow you to add an introduction. Here's the official page about [category templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates), and here's some sample code.

```
<?php if (is_category('Category A') && $paged < 2 ) : ?>
  <p>This is some text</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you're after an introduction on the first page, you'll want to remember the `$paged < 2`.